# How to index pdf file with lucene

Tags: java, mysql, pdf, lucene

i have to create a fulltext search with lucene in my project,so i have to index a blob column in mysql database(contains file pdf,doc,xsl,xml and image),with doc,xsl,and xml i dont have any problems but with the pdf file i cant get result

```
    public class Indexfile {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        RemoteControlServiceConnection a = new RemoteControlServiceConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test","root", "root" );
        Connection conn = a.getConnexionMySQL();
        final File INDEX_DIR = new File("index");
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(INDEX_DIR,
                new StandardAnalyzer(),
                true);

        String query = "SELECT id, name ,document FROM Table_document";
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while (result.next()) {
            Document document = new Document();
            document.add(new Field("id", result.getString("id"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
            document.add(new Field("name", result.getString("name"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
            document.add(new Field("document", result.getString("document"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
             writer.addDocument(text);
            }
        }

        writer.close();


    }
}
```

for search i use

```
    public class searchlucene {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    String qu = "montbel*"; // put your keyword here
   // String IndexStoreDir = "index-directory";
    try {
        Query q = new QueryParser("document", analyzer).parse(qu);
        int hitspp = 100; //hits per page
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.open("index"));
        TopDocCollector collector = new TopDocCollector(hitspp);
        searcher.search(q, collector);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
        System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
              int docId = hits[i].doc;
              Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
              System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("name"));
          }
          searcher.close();
      } catch (Exception ex1) {
      }
}}
```

Comment: I'm actually amazed that doc works, as that is a binary format. To index a PDF file, what I would do is get the PDF data, convert it to text using for example PDFBox and then index that text content. Perhaps you want to look to "upgrading" to using Apache SOLR however, which I believe has built-in capabilities to index specific file types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to convert the `PDF` file content to text, then add that text to the index.

**For Example:**

You can use `PDFBox` to convert the `pdf` content to text:

```
String contents = "";
PDDocument doc = null;
try {
    doc = PDDocument.load(file);
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

    stripper.setLineSeparator("\n");
    stripper.setStartPage(1);
    stripper.setEndPage(5);// this mean that it will index the first 5 pages only
    contents = stripper.getText(doc);

} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then add the content to `LuceneDocument`, example:

```
luceneDoc.add(new Field(CONTENT_FIELD, allContents.toString(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
```

Answer (score 8):

to Parse any kind of file use [Tika project](http://tika.apache.org/), then index it with Lucene.
Tika already contain too many APIs (pdfBox....)

Answer (score 0):

```
    First you can read your pdf through itext just like
try{
        PdfReader readerObj = new PdfReader("file path");
            int n = readerObj.getNumberOfPages();
            String content=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2); //Extracting the content from a particular page.
            document.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    add your pdf content to lucene document
    doc.add(new Field("pdfContent", content, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
```